# Show that $A=\{0,1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4},...\}$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

> Show that $A=\{0,1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4},...,\}$ is compact.

Suppose $K=\bigcup_{\alpha\in J} U_\alpha$ is a cover for $A$.

What I want to be able to say is that since $1$ is the limit of that sequence of numbers, then since $K$ is a cover for $A$, some $U_\alpha$ must contain $1$.

And since the limit of the sequence given is $1$, then all but finitely many members of the sequence will be contained in that $U_\alpha$, then only finitely many open sets of $K$ are needed to cover the remaining members of $A$.

Comment: that sounds good

Comment: Sure, that's fine. What's your question? I don't think you need anything more than what you have here. (So if you're asking if your answer is correct, it looks good.) You can unravel (e.g.) the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit to get an explicit finite open cover, but I don't think that would add anything to what you have here. Alternatively, note that $A$ is a closed subspace of the compact space $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @anomaly Well I don't know that $U_\alpha$ must be an open ball centred at $1$. I just know that it is an open set which contains $1$. But I guess I can say that there must be some open ball contained within $U_\alpha$ which is centred at $1$ and that will allow me to use limit definition?

Comment: Ah, OK. The set $U_\alpha$ is an open subspace of $A$, and $A$ has the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$. That means that sets of the form $(a, b)\cap A$ form a basis for the topology on $A$, which should give you the sets you need for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed solution looks good. To address your concern, $U_\alpha$ need not be an open ball centered at 1 and it still works. This is because as long as $U_\alpha$ contains 1, then $U_\alpha$ must contain some open ball around 1 by the definition of an open set.

Note: If we are allowed to use the Heine-Borel theorem, then the conclusion would immediately follow.